# var vs regular object declaration C#

Tags: c#

```
var foo1 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass foo2 = new SomeClass();
```

Does those two lines of code translate into the same IL, and how does the `dynamic` differ from them ? I know that `dynamic` uses some kind of technique called late binding but how does that work ?

Comment: This looks like a job for... the Skeet.

Comment: They are the same, there is no difference in IL. Question asked and answered many times.

Comment: Is your question actually about `var` (as per the title) or `dynamic` (as per the body)? They're completely different - and both are extensively documented.

Comment: I find lots of explanations of what `dynamic` does this after typing `dynamic c#` into my favourite search engine. Perhaps you could be more specific about which bits you don't understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does those two lines of code translate into the same IL?

Yes

> and how does the dynamic differ from them ?

Meaningless until you display member access; for example:

```
dynamic foo3 = new SomeClass();
foo3.SomeMethod();
```

Here, `SomeMethod` is resolved entirely at runtime via either a dynamic despatch layer or a cached meta-programming layer that sits on top of reflection (depending on what capabilities `SomeClass` has). In regular (non-dynamic) IL, it would just be a single `callvirt` opcode.